# Coffee clips when rendering image

Tags: rendering, materials, geometry, glass, reflection

[image]

As you can see here the coffee starts clipping and suddenly becomes invisible. And I don´t really know what to do...

Comment: maybe there are faces overlapping, try to scale the liquid a bit?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.  Could you draw on the image to indicate where you think the coffee is clipping?  It appears to me that there are reflections on the cup that are masking the coffee but I don't know if we're talking about the same part of scene.

Comment: you can see clearly the other side of the plate eventhough you should not see it

Comment: I have tried scaling the liquid to a bigger size but the problem still occurs

Comment: Coffee is there and what you see is caused by glass settings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The donut tutorial uses a method described here to get a good liquid appearance.

Source: [Aversis.be](http://www.aversis.be/tutorials/vray/vray-20-glass-liquid-02.htm)
[image]

I think you're running into the problem illustrated by the third wine glass.  Make sure the mesh of your liquid is clipping into the glass at all points.

Be aware, you can also run into a version of this problem if the glass and the liquid have different *Subdivision Surface* settings, because the interpolated points might fall slightly outside of the glass.